# Дайте совет пожалуйста по поводу ЧПУ

Tags: ссылки, чпу

Сайту около двух лет, имеет некоторую цитируемость в интернете, посещаемость в среднем 800 посетителей в день, проиндексирован поисковиками, но написан на ссылках типа index.php?go=view&id=332603 , Дайте совет стоит ли переписывать его на API /view/332603 , сильно ли при этом он потеряет позиции в поиске? Стоит ли того дело? Спасибо.

Comment: API проиндексирован?

Comment: При чем здесь API? Может Вы имели в виду ЧПУ? По идее стоит, но для начала должны работать ссылки обоих типов, перенаправляя пользователей со старых адресов на новые, это чтобы позиции не потерять особо. А через полгода-год (могу ошибаться, не SEO-шник) можно убирать ссылки старого формата

Comment: Да ,ЧПУ. Извините

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, хотелось бы немного рассказать о том, что набор символов идущий после адреса вашего сайта в соответствии с **RFC 3986** (*Стандарт унифицированного идентификатора ресурса*) называется путь (URI Path), а все что идет после знака вопроса называется **запрос** (URI Query), который может быть дополнен **фрагментом** (например *#link1*)

Обновление адресов, смена верстки - **это нормальная операция**. Рекомендации по выполнению подобных действий есть на официальных сайтах поисковых систем и там можно ознакомиться с тем, что нужно делать, чтобы не потерять позиции.

Например, **Яндекс** в своей статье описывает следующие действия:

> Как правило, изменить адреса страниц сайта необходимо в следующих
>   случаях:
>
> 1. смена структуры;
> 2. внедрение человеко-понятных URL (ЧПУ-адресов);
> 3. изменение или обновление CMS.
>
> Простое создание новой страницы не будет решением ситуации:
>   индексирующий робот будет воспринимать страницу по старому и новому
>   адресу как две отдельных страницы, которые будут индексироваться и
>   отображаться по запросам независимо друг от друга. Чтобы в результатах
>   поиска смена адреса страницы произошла корректно, рекомендуем
>   следующее:
>
> Настройте со старого адреса страницы перенаправление на новый (301 серверный редирект). В этом случае робот индексирует цель
>   перенаправления и удаляет из поиска ранее известные ему страницы. По
>   мере обхода сайта роботом в результатах поиска появляются новые
>   документы. При необходимости можно использовать цепочку редиректов:
>   индексироваться и участвовать в поиске будет конечная цель
>   перенаправления. Проверить индексирование страницы можно в разделе
>   Статистика обхода Яндекс.Вебмастера.
>
> Проверьте, что новый адрес страницы доступен для робота, сервер отвечает кодом 200 ОК и отдает контент. Сделать это можно с помощью
>   инструмента Яндекс.Вебмастера Проверка ответа сервера. Также
>   убедитесь, что наиболее важные страницы не запрещены для
>   индексирования в файле robots.txt с помощью инструмента Анализ
>   robots.txt.
>
> Если какие-то определенные страницы уже отсутствуют на сайте, однако тематика сайта не изменилась и на нем можно найти схожие товары
>   (фильмы, статьи и т. д.), настройте 301 редирект на главную страницу
>   соответствующего раздела или в раздел со схожей тематикой. Если вместе
>   со структурой сайта меняется его тематика, необходимо настроить сервер
>   таким образом, чтобы прежние страницы отдавали в заголовке код
>   HTTP-404. В этом случае старые страницы будут удалены из выдачи после
>   их переобхода роботом. Чтобы ускорить удаление несуществующих разделов
>   или типов страниц, можно указать в файле robots.txt запрет на их
>   индексирование.
>
> Ускорить индексирование новых страниц поможет инструмент Переобход страниц. Отправленные на переобход страницы смогут попасть в поиск в
>   течение двух недель. Старые страницы с перенаправлением также можно
>   отправить на переобход. Это поможет роботу быстрее отследить
>   установленный на них редирект и исключить из поиска (так же в течение
>   двух недель). Рекомендуем ознакомиться с нашими общими советами по
>   индексированию.
>
> Добавьте новые страницы в файл Sitemap сайта или создайте новый файл Sitemap, в котором будут указаны ссылки на страницы по новым
>   адресам.
>
> Проверьте, что в меню навигации сайта уже указаны новые адреса. В разделе Внешние ссылки вы можете увидеть, какие сторонние ресурсы
>   ссылаются на старые страницы сайта. По возможности попросите
>   владельцев этих ресурсов изменить адреса ссылок на актуальные.

[Яндекс - Смена структуры и дизайна сайта](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/recommendations/changing-site-structure.xml)

Comment: подскажите, а для чего в конец ЧПУ добавляют .php или .html ?

Comment: Честно говоря, насколько мне известно это не играет на ранжирование, поэтому это лишь дело вкуса того, кто определяет схему именования путей на сайте. Мне например, удобнее когда расширения в ссылке не обозначены.

Answer (score 2):

Я не СЕО`шник и не в курсе того, как это повлияет на выдачу, но могу рассказать как выполнял подобную задачу.
Сначала сделали поддержку ЧПУ не отключая ссылки такого вида index.php?go=view&id=332603, потом сделали 301 редирект со старых на новые.

Ну а потом, когда поисковики проиндексировали новые ссылки, отключили поддержку старых ссылок.